# Akka and Backpressure

Tags: akka

I see the concept of backpressure with Akka Streams but my Project is not using the Akka Stream and I developed another concept for backpressure indicator for Akka and I like to ask here it is viable or not...

I am planning to use the depth of the Mailbox Queues as a criterion to use as backpressure....the logic behind it, if Akka can keep up with the speed of me producing messages, the depth of the message queue should be shallow. If I send too many messages and Akka can't keep up there will be more and more messages in the Message Queues and I have to slow the rate I produce the messages.

It is basically same idea from Apache Cassandra's 'in flight requests'...

```
Session.State state = session.getState();
for (Host host : state.getConnectedHosts()) {
   HostDistance distance = loadBalancingPolicy.distance(host);
   int connections = state.getOpenConnections(host);
   int inFlightQueries = state.getInFlightQueries(host);
   ....
}
```

So I find from the Akka reference.conf that Akka uses..

```
default-mailbox {
  mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.SingleConsumerOnlyUnboundedMailbox"
}

class NodeMessageQueue extends AbstractNodeQueue[Envelope] with MessageQueue with 
  UnboundedMessageQueueSemantics {

 final def enqueue(receiver: ActorRef, handle: Envelope): Unit = add(handle)

 final def dequeue(): Envelope = poll()
```

So I wrote an AspectJ Aspect to intercept enqueue() and dequeue() and I increment and decrement a global AtomicLong, which I can use to track the total count of messages waiting in the mailboxes of Akka Actor...

So my logic if Akka can keep up with the number of the messages I am sending, the number should below some preconfigured value...

So let's say I have 100 000 actors and they have 1000 Messages in Mailbox Message Queues, everything ist Ok, but if I see 1 000 000 Messages waiting in the Message Queues, it is a signal to slow down my Message production....and if it is 10 000 000 Messages in the queue a definitive signal stop message production...

I build a prototype and it works as I expect....but before I proceed, I like to ask here, do you see anything really flawed about the concept.

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 1):

It's potentially viable, but:

- a single point of contention (even something lock-free) on every message send is likely to have a substantial performance impact under high volume
- the particular threshold where you would want to slow down is going to depend a lot on the application and will probably change as you change the application
- depending on the particulars of the system (and what exactly is meant by "stop message production"), there's a possibility of deadlock (i.e. if you have a requirement to not drop an incoming message and processing a message entails sending another message (sending at least one message as part of processing a message is perhaps the single most common thing to do in Akka), that implies that the actor will stop processing from its mailbox).

Comment: - Yeah, I have some reservation about AtomicLong increments, that will be the next thing I will put under load test and check. As an alternative I am considering to place the increments/decrements to concurrentLinkedQueue and process those asynchronously, that will decouple it from enqueue/dequeue... -I am planning to publish this information to Prometheus/Grafana so we can first observe the application behaviour then configure over application properties to where to slow down and where to stop - We are consuming messages from Kafka, so my plan is to stop Kafka Consumers.

Comment: Honestly, if you're consuming from Kafka, I would suggest just using Alpakka Kafka and `mapAsync` with an ask to backpressure.

Comment: Yeah, that is an option, but I have no influence to direct the project to this direction and we also have other Event sources that I might have to stop (or slow down) so I am trying to find a genertic way....